# MongoDB - Update objects in side a nested array in a collection (nested updating)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

**Coupen Collection Before Update**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("571501b7cbd85fe5ce5a749c"),
    "storeCode": "LULUMALL",
    "offers": [{
            "name": "offer1",
            "coupens": [
                { "coupen": "adssd", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "sdsafa", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "wewerw", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "cvvdf", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfdfadf", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfdfd", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfdf", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfsdf", "status": "open" }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "offer2",
        "coupens": [
            { "coupen": "dffddd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "sdfsdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "sfsdfd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dffdfd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "sdfsdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfsdff", "status": "open" },
        ]
    }]
}
```

I have `storeCode`,`offer name`&`coupen`.So i need to update the `status` of the corresponding  object to `alloted`.

For Ex:if `storeCode` =LULUMALL ,`name`=offer1& `coupen`=adssd,So i need to update the `status` of the corresponding object to `allotted`.After update,The Collection should be like this.
 **Coupen Collection After Update**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("571501b7cbd85fe5ce5a749c"),
    "storeCode": "LULUMALL",
    "offers": [{
            "name": "offer1",
            "coupens": [
                { "coupen": "adssd", "status": "allotted" },
                { "coupen": "sdsafa", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "wewerw", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "cvvdf", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfdfadf", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfdfd", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfdf", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfsdf", "status": "open" }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "offer2",
        "coupens": [
            { "coupen": "dffddd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "sdfsdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "sfsdfd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dffdfd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "sdfsdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfsdff", "status": "open" },
        ]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied these data in to a new variable and change the value of `status` field  to `allotted` based on the condition.

Here shopData is the input data

```
var updateData = shopData;
```

`updateData` is the copy of  `shopData`.

```
updateCoupen.offers[index].coupens[randomNo].status = 'allotted';
```

`index` and `randomNo` will get based on the condition.

```
Coupen.update({ "storeCode": store }, { $set: { 'offers': updateData.offers } }, function(err, numAffected) {
    console.log('numAffected', numAffected);

})
```

**Complete Code**

```
var store = 'LULUMALL';
var name = 'offer1';
var coupen = 'adssd';
var shopData = {
    "_id": ObjectId("571501b7cbd85fe5ce5a749c"),
    "storeCode": "LULUMALL",
    "offers": [{
            "name": "offer1",
            "coupens": [
                { "coupen": "adssd", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "sdsafa", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "wewerw", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "cvvdf", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfdfadf", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfdfd", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfdf", "status": "open" },
                { "coupen": "dfsdf", "status": "open" }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "offer2",
        "coupens": [
            { "coupen": "dffddd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "sdfsdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "sfsdfd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dffdfd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "sdfsdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdd", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfdfdf", "status": "open" },
            { "coupen": "dfsdff", "status": "open" },
        ]
    }]
}

for (var i = 0; i < shopData.offers.length; i++) {
    if (shopData.offers[i].name === offer) {
        var coupen = [];
        var index = i;
        for (var j = 0; j < shopData.offers[i].coupens.length; j++) {
            if (shopData.offers[i].coupens[j].status === "open") {

                coupen.push(shopData.offers[i].coupens[j]);
            }
        }
        console.log('Available Coupens', coupen);
        var randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * coupen.length);
        var rand = coupen[randomNo];
        var updateCoupen = shopData;
        updateCoupen.offers[index].coupens[randomNo].status = 'allotted';
        Coupen.update({ "storeCode": store }, { $set: { 'offers': updateCoupen.offers } }, function(err, numAffected) {
            console.log('numAffected', numAffected);

        })

    }
}
```